# Tensorflow variable scope kernel and bias default initializers

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

TensorFlow's variable scope(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) has a parameter called 'initializer' which gives a common initializer for all weights in this scope. However we know that kernel weights and bias weights are initialised differently. So does this parameter affect both types of weights? If so is there any way to specify different initializers for kernel and biases ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "However we know that kernel weights and bias weights are initialised differently" ?

Comment: kernel weights may be initialised from a normal distribution whereas bias is zero initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In Keras which run tensorflow at backend, uses this:
kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'.

Please go through: https://keras.io/initializers/